# DynamoDB Transaction Write

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

DynamoDB's transaction write states:

> Multiple transactions updating the same items simultaneously can cause conflicts that cancel the transactions. We recommend following DynamoDB best practices for data modeling to minimize such conflicts.

If there are multiple simultaneous `TransactionWriteItems` on the same item simultaneously, will all the transaction write request fail with `TransactionCanceledException`? Or at least one request will succeed?

Answer (score 0):

This purely depends on how the conflicts happen. So, if all the writes in a transaction get successful, it will be successful. If some other write/trasaction midifies one of the items, it will fail.